# How to Search a List of Names in iOS?

Tags: ios, search, ios5, xcode4.2

So basically I want to use a UISearchBar to search an Array of Names.
Inside the Array the Names have this Format:

[FIRST NAME] ([SECOND NAME]) [LAST NAME]

Using

```
 if (![string rangeOfString:seachTextPart].location == NSNotFound)
```

I have managed to search Names entering ONLY the FIRST NAME into the UISearchBar.
But as soon as I enter a SPACE i get NO RESULTS.

Also I want to be able to search by entering just the LAST NAME.
Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please mark the correct answer or otherwise provide the comment for why the answer does not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your format is follow:`name = @"[John]([James])[Smith]";`

Searching `[name rangeOfString:@"John"]` would yield found.

Searching `[name rangeOfString:@"John "]` would yield not found, since `@"John "` is not in *name*

But in this case, `[name rangeOfString:@"Smith"]` would yield found.

Try this: Remove all spaces and lower case strings

```
   searchTerm = [[searchTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] lowercaseString];
   NSRange searchName = [[name lowercaseString] rangeOfString:searchTerm];
```

If you want to test, just simply do this"
 `if (searchName == 0) //it does not match`

Answer (score 0):

Byte's code works unless they type "John Smith."  If you want something more robust you can use `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator` and then search for any of the strings in the Array.  So Typing "John Smith" would return all of the Johns and all of the Smiths

here:

```
NSArray *theTerms = [searchTerm componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

then run a for loop through all of `theTerms` and check them against your names adding the ones that contain the search terms to an array and then displaying them.